# Accessing contacts email picker on Sony devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

My application uses the phones inbuilt contact picker to allow the user to select an email address. The problem I am having is that this works on my Nexus 5 (Lollipop) and Samsungs (KitKat), but not on the Sony Experia Z1 (KitKat).

I understand that obviously the activity is not found, but I cannot find an alternative compatible with the Sony build of Android, but this must be possible somehow?

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And here is the exception being thrown:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/emails }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
at com.mtickner.runningmotivator.FriendListActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(FriendListActivity.java:73)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:556)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18553)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit**

This permission is in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It is bug with the Sony phone.  You can make sure the app doesn't crash by check that an activity is available for the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);

if(getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,0) != null)
{
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this as I don't have access to a Sony phone currently, but that looks like a good solution. The one I used at the time involves catching the exception, but this looks neater. Will post my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The fix suggested by [Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31146916/3201989) is definitely a great one as it targets not only Sony devices but also any other device that may have this issue.

Unfortunately, from Lollipop on, the fix is not working anymore for Sony devices.

Indeed, from Android 5.0, Sony devices open the contact app without a problem but throw a SecurityException when actually picking a contact...
I fixed it by being a bit more restrictive when checking.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);

if(getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,0) != null &&
!Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Sony"))
{
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with for this involved catching the exception that was thrown in order to display an error message. I didn't manage to find an alternative that worked, although I haven't been able to try on Sony's version of Lollipop.

```
// Launch the contacts picker activity
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Catch exception thrown when contacts picker is not found (Sony devices)
    e.printStackTrace();

    // Display error message etc...
}
```

@Wombat's solution looks like it would be more efficient in terms of avoiding the exception, but I thought I would add this to help others in future.